# How to associate multiple tables on Exposed

Tags: api, kotlin, orm

Now I'm creating an API using Kotlin with Exposed, Ktor and Postgres.
When I need to do some select on a table which is associated with another table I have to "parse" the ResultRow to an entity object. If this table have more associations I do have to repeat the association every time, what is weird.

Is there an easy way to do it? 
Cuz I think to write a lot of code to create the objects it too much!

Now I'm doing like this.

```java
fun ResultRow.toInterval() = Interval(
    this[Intervals.idInterval],
    Setting(
        this[OfficeSettings.idOffice],
        Office(
            this[Offices.idOffice],
            this[Offices.code],
            this[Offices.name]
        ),
        this[OfficeSettings.scheduleDaysRule],
        this[OfficeSettings.serviceTimeRule],
        this[OfficeSettings.countInterval],
        this[OfficeSettings.restTimeRule]
    ),
    this[Intervals.date],
    this[Intervals.startTime],
    this[Intervals.endTime]
)
```

Just to parse the result into an Interval, which is associated with a Setting, and Setting is associated with an Office.